# Creating a plot without an x-axis and automatic ticks for the y-axis

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a function with specific options for the appearance of the plot. I want the X axis to not show up, and the Y axis to be labeled normally (i.e. numbers outside the plot)..
Yet, I don't get any numbers in the Y axis' ticks:

[image]

The code I am using is the following (the function to be plotted is different, but still returns this behavior):

```
Plot[5 t + 3, {t, 0, 10},
    PlotRange -> All,
    AxesOrigin -> {10, 0},     
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 40},
    Axes -> {False, True},
    PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.007], Darker[Blue, 0.5]}},     
    AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], ImageSize -> {640, 480}
]
```

Could you please help me get the ticks numbered automatically?

Comment: That doesn't help me. Either I get blank space within the plot when I change `AxesOrigin`, and resizing does no change to the plot :S

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your plot is that you are using the y-axis on the left, but positioning it on the right by shifting the origin. However, its behaviour is still that of a left-axis (i.e., ticks are to the left of the line). What you need is a *right*-axis, where the ticks are to the right (with the origin remaining where it should be).

You can do this by using `Frame` and setting only the right frame to be visible. Note that all the `Axes*` options will now be named `Frame*`.

```
Plot[5 t + 3, {t, 0, 10}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 40}, 
    Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.007], Darker[Blue, 0.5]}}, 
    FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], ImageSize -> {640, 480}, 
    PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see!! Thanks, I will check it out now! Looks great!

Edit:Indeed, it works great! Thanks again!

Comment: `AxesOrigin` is unnecessary. Only nitpicking because you beat me by 1 sec :)

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to switch from axes to frame. And you may not be able to use a frame if the axis happens to be inside the plot instead of at the border.

So the way to get what you want with the *minimum* changes to your original code is this:

```
Plot[5 t + 3, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {10, 0}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 40}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.007], Darker[Blue, 0.5]}}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Opacity[0], AbsoluteThickness[3]}, 
 ImageSize -> {640, 480}]
```

All I did is to remove `Axes -> {False, True},` and then modified the `AxesStyle` to make the x axis invisible.

To see how this differs from the solution using `Frame`, I'll move the axis into the middle:

```
Plot[5 t + 3, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {5, 0}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 40}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.007], Darker[Blue, 0.5]}}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Opacity[0], AbsoluteThickness[3]}, 
 ImageSize -> {640, 480}]
```

[image: One axis]

Comment: _"... Y axis to be labeled normally (i.e. numbers outside the plot)..."_ That's why I used a frame. Yours still puts the numbers inside the plot. Of course, you could possibly control it with a tick function, but then it isn't minimal anymore :)

Comment: @R.M Well, if you're going to take things literally: I could just change mine to `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}`...

Comment: Nah, I interpreted their question as wanting to place the axis to the right, but since they didn't know how to, they simply moved it as far right as possible. I do agree that yours is useful, since you can't have frames in arbitrary positions

Comment: Indeed I wanted to have the axis on the right-hand side. Yet, thanks for your help Jens, I learnt something now! :)